# MNIST dataset, what is this condition?

Tags: python, opencv, mnist

What is this number 0.88 in training mnist dataset

```
bw=((color.rgb2gray(mnist_picture)/255.0)>0.88).astype('uint8')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 conversions in that line: colour -> greyscale -> black & white.

The first conversion, from colour to greyscale, is performed using the

```
rgb2gray(...)
```

function.

The second conversion, from greyscale to black & white, is done by thresholding the range of greys so that any dark grey colour (with value > 0.88) is converted to black, and the others to white.

The 0.88 is an arbitrary value. Any threshold value that makes the converted black & white characters legible would be just as valid to use. Try experimenting with a few different threshold values to see their effect.